# Sublime Text não funciona corretamente

Tags: c++, sublime-text

Eu instalei o Sublime Text no meu linux. eu abri o arquivo teste.cpp que contem o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Mas quando eu executo o código só aparece: **[Finished in 0.9s]**

O hello world não aparece, e quando eu coloco algum comando de leitura também não. Pensei que ele não estivesse executando meu código, mas só tem ele aberto no sublime, não sei conferir.

Answer (score 2):

O problema não é com o sublime text e sim com o `system("pause");`no ambiente linux.

Substitua por:

```
std::cout << "Press enter to continue ...";
std::cin.get();
```

Comment: Então, eu substituir o que voce falou, mas mesmo assim da no mesmo. eu deixei só o cout e também continua

Comment: Mas você precisa deixar o `cin.get();` para aguardar que você digite alguma coisa antes de encerrar.

Comment: Eu formulei errado. Eu quis dizer que eu substitui o que você pediu : `std::cout << "Press enter to continue ...";
std::cin.get(); `  e eu também tentei deixei só `cout << "Hello World!" << endl; ` e mesmo assim continua. Acho que é o compilador, mas eu baixei certo o gcc.